# lua string editing or cutting

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table. This table name is tmpTbl, and tmpTbl[8] value is `<a href="currentsong?sid=1">Pit .2017 - 06-24.203008</a>`

For me this `<a href="currentsong?sid=1">` and `</a>` part does not have to.

how can I get this out of it?

String: `<a href="currentsong?sid=1">Pit .2017 - 06-24.203008</a>`
I'd like this:

```
Pit .2017 - 06-24.203008
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `tmpTbl[8]:match(">(.-)<")` extracts the text. It finds the first `>` and captures everything until the first `<`.